# Performance difference in loop

Tags: c#, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between declaring variables before or in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop)

Is there any (or any notable) performance difference when I write for example something like this (consider loading tens or hundreds of thousands rows from DB into the collection of Foo objects):

```
...
Foo myFoo;

while(reader.Read())
{
    myFoo = new Foo();
    myFoo.SomeProperty = reader.GetValue(0);
    ...
    fooCollection.Add(myFoo);
}
```

or this

```
...

while(reader.Read())
{
    Foo myFoo = new Foo();
    myFoo.SomeProperty = reader.GetValue(0);
    ...
    fooCollection.Add(myFoo);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407255/difference-between-declaring-variables-before-or-in-loop

Comment: Chrisf, Yes, it is a duplicate but not an obvious one.

Comment: Only sure way to find out is to write some code and time it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the compiler will generate the same IL in each instance.

See similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632444/foreach-performance-wise-should-we-declare-variable-once-before-loop-or-inside) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110083/which-loop-has-better-performance-why#110389).

Answer (score 4):

You're creating a new instance of Foo in each iteration of the loop in both snippets so I wouldn't expect to see a difference.

You should profile your code though, using a tool like eqatec  profiler:

http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler